# make view floatable on some other view

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, floating

I am having one view in ipad.
    On that view , I am having four buttons.
    Now when I click on that button , one view is opening with some fixed height,width,x position and y position.
     I want to make this new view dock-able.
     I mean I want to drag this view to anywhere on that big view.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [following](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

1. `– touchesBegan:withEvent:`
2. `– touchesMoved:withEvent:`
3. `– touchesEnded:withEvent:`
4. `– touchesCancelled:withEvent:`

And use the locations of touch to set the frame of the uiview. Its not complicated to do so.

A quick google search yielded this [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/).

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize this in your situation..

```
 -(void)dragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
//NSLog(@"Received a pan gesture");
self.panCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];


}
CGPoint newCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
float dX = newCoord.x-panCoord.x;
float dY = newCoord.y-panCoord.y;

gesture.view.frame = CGRectMake(gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX,          gesture.view.frame.origin.y+dY, gesture.view.frame.size.width, gesture.view.frame.size.height);
}
```